Add an instanced modifier on different objects
I want to apply an instanced modifier to 5 different objects. So when I change a value in the modifier the value is changed on all objects. Is this possible?

What about using drivers to copy the value entered in the "master" modifier, to the "slave" drivers attached to the remaining objects ?

Yes, it is possible.
To add a modifier to several objects, select them and then go to 'copy selected' in the modifier.

Secondly, to change the value of a modifier for a group of objects at the same time you can press and hold alt while changing the value.

If it doesn't work, it may be useful to turn off 3 button mouse emulation in preferences >> input.

Thank you. Does the job.

As far as I am aware, you cannot link modifiers. However it is possible to achieve a similar result using drivers in the following manner.

create the same modifier on all other objects.
now for each parameter you want to change repeat steps 3 to ...:
select the "reference" object and right click on a parameter you want to change and click copy data path
now select another object. and right click on the same variable, and click add driver
below add input variable click on the (X) symbol and select single property
now in the Prop: section select the reference object
In the path section you need to paste the path you copied
finally change the expression to be equal to 'var'

If you do this for each of the parameters and objects, changing the reference object modifier will automatically change all others accordingly.
Tip: Once you created one driver you can rightclick on the purple property -> copy driver then you can paste the driver over any other property.
